# Search in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a search option for my project , i tried with some code it does not shows any error or any warning but the result is not correct.

controller

```
function search_package()
{
    $package_id = $this->input->post('search');
    $data['result'] = $this->my_model->search($package_id);
    $this->load->view('destinations/search',$data);
}
```

model

```
function search($package_id)
{
    $this->db->like('category_id',$package_id);
    $query = $this->db->get('gt_package');
    return $query->result();
}
```

view

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/package_view/search_package">                       
    <label>Select an option</label>
    <select class="typeahead form-control" name="search">
        <?php 
            foreach($search as $s)
            {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $s->category_id;?>"><?php echo $s->category_name;?></option>
            <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search Now" />
</form>
```

my db structure

[image]

Comment: what result your are getting ? and what you want ?

Comment: ex: i want record only with category_id '8' but here i am getting both records

Comment: both records .?

Comment: ie, the category id with 8 and 9

Comment: use where instead of like

Comment: what you want to search category id or package id ?

Comment: use where not like in search. $this->db->where('category_id',$package_id);

Comment: i want to search with category_id  ex : i want to get all packages with a specific category_id

Comment: @Lomesh i tried using where at first but but it does not shows any result.

Comment: try to echo $this->db->last_query(); then post it here

Comment: ok, then print  u r query using $this->db->last_query(); and through in mysql  and check the response and query.

Comment: result for last_query : SELECT * FROM (`gt_package`) WHERE `category_id` LIKE '%%'

Comment: check the value you are getting for `$package_id` in your controller. `echo $package_id; exit;`

Comment: oh sorry to all i cleared it , i forgot to write method="post" in form.

Answer (score 0):

> If we're searching word we can use `db->like`(it will produce `%text%`). But you're searching an integer, So I suggest you to, use `db->where`.

```
$this->db->where('category_id',$package_id); #changed
$query = $this->db->get('gt_package');
return $query->result_array(); #changed
```

And in view

```
<option value="<?php echo $s['category_id'];?>"><?php echo $s['category_name'];?></option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     model

                     $query=$this->db->query("select col from tbl WHERE 
                       category_id  like'%'.$package_id.'%';
                      return $query->result_array();
    view
```

```
         <?php 
           foreach($result as $results){

            echo $results['col'];
         }
```

Comment: Code is great in an answer, however, please add amplifying information explaining why the code solves the problem.